# TLS to secure external client server application

Tags: security, ssl

is it possible to use transaction layer security (tls) to secure an external client/server application without modifying the code of the application itself?

Say a client application on a machine connects to several servers on several machines over an unsecured connection. I want to encrypt this connection using openssl/tls, but I can't modify neither client nor servers, but the machine configurations (linux os running underneath). I just found [stunnel](https://www.stunnel.org/index.html) but it seems that it just supports a 1:1 connection.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have a finite (and reasonably small) number of servers and you can configure the port number on your client for each connection, you could run `stunnel` on multiple ports, each one corresponding to a different destination.

However, it sounds like setting up a VPN between all these machines would be a better option. Some VPN implementations rely on TLS, but I'm not sure it would be the best choice here. You might want to investigate other methods, such as IPSec too.